# Gerar contagem de numero ao clicar

Tags: javascript

Tem alguma forma de ao clicar em algum elemento atualize o numero de uma `tag` para um valor maior?

Ex: o valor da `tag` padrão é `1`, sendo a tag `n`, `n="1"` ao clicar no elemento atualiza para `n="2"` e assim consecutivamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu objetivo é marcar apenas no browser, segue um exemplo. Mas como você indicou a tag PHP na pergunta... se você quiser persistir essa contagem no servidor, precisará preparar uma estrutura para armazenar essas informações.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  
  $('.tag').on('click', function(){
      var contador = $(this).attr('n');
      var total = ++contador;
      $(this).find('span:first').text(total);
      $(this).attr('n', total);
     
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color: #ccc;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  min-width: 30px;
  float:left;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag" n="0"> tag (<span class="count">0</span>)</div>
<div class="tag" n="0"> outra tag (<span class="count">0</span>)</div>
```

Comment: Valeu cara. A primeira forma que você colocou resolveu meu problema, pois era exatamente o que eu precisava para atualizar os campos de numeração para identificação dos itens sem ter conflito.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar `setAttribute` e incrementando o valor a cada clique com `addEventListener`.

Coloquei um contador nos botões para ilustrar, mas se você visualizar pelo "*inspecionar elemento*" do navegador, verá que o atributo `n` está sendo igualmente alterado.

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("#tags button");
for(x=0; x < els.length; x++){
   els[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var soma = parseInt(this.getAttribute("n"))+1;
      this.setAttribute("n",soma);
      this.innerText = soma;
   });
}
```

```html
<div id="tags">
<button type="button" n="1">1</button>
<button type="button" n="1">1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um botão que ao clicar incrementa o valor do input ou qualquer outra tag. Segue um exemplo:

```
  var botao = document.getElementById('botao');
  botao.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var valor_atual = input.value;
    valor_atual++;
    input.value = valor_atual;
  });
```